# cannot open a facebook session with the SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to post a message on my Facebook wall, here is a sample of my code:

```
 @Click (R.id.img_btn_facebook)
 @UiThread
 public void fbPostWall(){

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    SessionState state = SessionState.OPENING;

    if (session == null)
      TestManager.getInstance().setActivity(getActivity()).setLoginListener(this).facebookLogin();

    Log.e("SESSION-STATUS", "" + session.getState());

    if (session != null || state.isOpened()){

        Log.e("FACEBOOK", "post link on the wall ...");
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "This is a test");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
                new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
                        session,
                        params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                           FacebookException error) {
                        if (error == null) {
                            // When the story is posted, echo the success
                            // and the post Id.
                            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                        "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                // User clicked the Cancel button
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Publish cancelled",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Publish cancelled",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // Generic, ex: network error
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error posting story",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }
}
```

When I click on the "img_btn_facebook" button a login session is opened if the user isn't already on Facebook. After that, the Log.e("SESSION-STATUS", "" + session.getState()); Always give SESSION-STATUS﹕ OPENING But the point is that I always get this error message from the Facebook SDK:
com.facebook.FacebookException: Attempted to use a Session that was not open.

someone can help me please to fix it? I would like to post a message on my facebook wall thanks my Android app.

Answer (score 1):

Did you included onActivityResult ??

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);
        }
```

and in you manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

and **make sure that you have correct hash-key value in your facebook app**

To generate hash-key,include following line of code in your main activity

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

You will get hash key in console,include that key in facebook devleopr

Comment: Hi Kamlesh Arya and thanks for your interest. Absolutely not. Should I just add this method to make it works?

Comment: yup..facebook send its request back to onActivityresult

Comment: I always get the same error even if onActivityResult() is added.

Comment: post you manifest file.and add correct hash-key value in facebook developer

Comment: Thanks for your help Kamlesh, here is a link to my manifest = http://pastie.org/private/a1cxypyshwxpcak2uksya The hash key is properly setup in my Facebook app settings.

Comment: i dint find any problem in your code,did u added correct package name and class name on developer?i.e of your MainActivity.java?

Comment: I check up the hole code and it drive me crazy, I'm stuck with this error from the Facebook SDK = Attempted to use a Session that was not open.

Comment: Maybe one solution, the sandbox from the Facebook App Settings can be guilty of this kind of errors?

Comment: I still need help please, here is a dump of my Session = SESSION-STATE﹕ {Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:$$$$$$$$$$$$}

Comment: yeah.as katcha said..disable your facebook app's sandbox mode.

Comment: Katcha it's me the owner of this post, thanks anyway! :D

Answer (score 0):

**For someone having trouble with facebook sdk:**

**1 Download the samples**, test them to see if it`s not your mobile (**change the app id on sample to match yours**);

2 **Dont use a activity or fragment that has other purpose for facebook login**, instead **create one just for that**, **its probably a conflict**.

3 **Copy** the facebook **sample class** you need (choose the activity or fragment) **and call it through your code**.

4 Adapt copied class to your needs.